# How to compare a synonym type with a custom type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, synonym

I'm trying to learn haskell for a class, an I have a homework that requires me to compare a synonym type: `Critere = Acteur -> Bool` with the custom one `Acteur`.
I need to compare every acteur on a list to be sure they match every `Critere` on an other list... that's my code so far

```
data Acteur = Acteur Nom Sexe RevenuMinimum Date' Restriction ListeFilms
type Critere = Acteur -> Bool 
instance Ord Acteur where
  compare x y
   | nomActeur x == nomActeur y = EQ
   | nomActeur x < nomActeur y = LT
   | otherwise = GT
eqActeur (Acteur nom1 _ _ _ _ _) (Acteur nom2 _ _ _ _ _ ) = nom1 == nom2
instance Eq Acteur where
  (==)  = eqActeur
```

This is what the teacher gave me realate to the type Acteur... that's my answer so far:

```
selectionActeursCriteres :: [Critere] -> [Acteur] -> [Acteur]
selectionActeursCriteres [] (x:xs) = (x:xs)
selectionActeursCriteres (x:xs) [] = []
selectionActeursCriteres (x:xs) (y:ys) = t where
      t = selectionActeursCriteres tail (x:xs) [z | z <- ys, x == y]
```

I've tried to join the teacher like two days ago, and I'm still waiting...
Thanks you for your help in advance!

Comment: So, what exactly is your question here?

Comment: I got this error when i'm trying to launch it TP1.hs:116:66: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Acteur' with `Acteur -> Bool'
      Expected type: Critere
        Actual type: Acteur
    * In the second argument of `(==)', namely `y'
      In the expression: x == y
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x == y

Comment: I thinks its when i'm comparing acteur with critere... it doesn't work with my ==

Comment: It work thanks! i'm so use with OO, haskell is weird for me ahah! thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add error messages you're asking about to the question, in the future.